# Access published page id based on meta data component's content using graphQL / content service

Tags: content-delivery, cme, content-manager

In SDL Tridion, We would like to get published page IDs on the basis of metadata contents.
Let's say the metadata of the page contains "Test" so we would like to fetch all the published page ID which contains "Test" in their metadata.

The challenge here is whether we can fetch using graphQL or content service.

Please suggest and help here.

Comment: The answer is yes, to both. Can you share what you found so far, what queries you tried? This would help us provide better advice.

Comment: Hi @NunoLinhares, So far, we have tried to fetch from broker database with SQL query, but this is not what we want. In order to fetch data, we needed to use graphQL / content services. The metadata is component and that component is attached to a page. Now we want to fetch the published page id that contains specific metadata contents. Could you please share how can we fetch that ?

Comment: There are some really good GraphQL examples here: https://itsneeteshnarvaria.blogspot.com/2021/08/java-example-to-fetch-tridion-content.html - including how to resolve a component link, querying with Criteria, etc. And yes, querying the DB directly is not the right approach, as database models can change between versions, and this defeats the whole purpose of using webservices...